# One item went to second line

Tags: wordpress, menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P260c.jpg)

In menu when I added Contact Item .. it went to second line

Does anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Are you able to post the code that appears in your header.php file as an image alone, provides limited information.  It may be that a </div> tag could be causing the issue or your rows/columns not setup the way you want them etc.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be enough space for all the menu items. You can fix this by:
1. reduce the gap
2. reduce the font size
3. Increase the space for menu